# Is there a precedent for posting video answers on YouTube?

Tags: discussion

This idea came up in the discussion area of the Woodworking Community (now in the commitment phase). I suggested that we shoot some sample video answers as a way to get some exposure for the community and start building a precedent for video answers in general. As you can imagine with something like woodworking, a visual demonstration is sometimes the only way to illustrate concepts effectively.

But it brings up a bit of a dilemma: publicly posting a video in this way, for better or worse, makes me a representative of Stack Exchange, and I'm guessing I don't have that authority. Has this come up before and if so how was it handled?

Does Stack Exchange have the architecture to handle posting videos directly?

Answer (score 5):

Why do you think posting a video of an answer makes you a representative of Stack Exchange?

There is nothing stopping you creating a video and posting it as long as you don't imply you are doing this officially or on behalf of Stack Exchange. If you set up a YouTube channel you cannot use the Stack Exchange logo or the DIY logo, but you can reference the site and even link to the answer you are demonstrating.

If you think an answer is best served by posting a video then you can do that as well - as long as the answer contains enough of a description to make it an answer without the video and you make it clear in the answer what the video is of.

If there's enough demand for this we can request that videos can be embedded in posts in the same way as there are on [Arqade/Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

Stack Exchange doesn't host - nor should it host - videos. (It even outsources the hosting of images).

Comment: if i say in the video "this is an answer to a question on the DIY SE" to some small degree I'm acting in the capacity of a representative. If I don't make any mention of the SE nor explain the purpose of what I'm up to, and someone follows the link from YouTube to SE (which is kind of the point initially), I'm afraid their initial experience here would be confusing.

Comment: @paperstreet I don't see that there anything official. I didn't say you shouldn't mention Stack Exchange, just that you can't use the logos.

Comment: @paperstreet How do you come to the conclusion that you are somehow representing Stack Exchange by simply answering a question?

Comment: @paperstreet I'm not entirely sure what your concern here is. Saying "I made this video to answer a question" doesn't make you our representative in any legal sense. There are plenty of videos on Youtube that make marginal sense without whatever context they were made in (or even with :)). That's okay.

Comment: I'm just asking for guidance here, surely you all can imagine language that crosses a line without the help of copyrighted logos. As for making "marginal sense", this is what I'm really trying to avoid. Frankly the initiation for new comers into the SE is bruising and baffling enough without coming to it via an unsanctioned video that unofficially ties into a community that doesn't even really exist yet...is the point really not getting across or are you all just trying to not get your fingerprints on a perceived train wreck here?

Comment: @paperstreet No, as far as I can tell we understood your point perfectly. All you really have to do is avoid saying something obvious like "Stack Exchange endorses my video" or "I work for Stack Exchange" neither of which are true.

Comment: @MH  Is this something the SE would eventually support officially if it shows promise? Is there a path to legitimacy for us? I keep imagining this future where myself and all the other willing volunteers spend untold amounts of personal investment making this happen, and then when the concept is proven successful, SE management swoops in and starts an official SE YouTube Channel and leaves us out in the cold.

Comment: @paperstreet [They tried that already. It didn't work.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270574/1068283)

Comment: @paperstreet You may be putting the cart before the horse here. :) We're talking about a purely hypothetical successful extensive video collection. We don't have any plans to introduce a video component right now. Text is still king, though supplementary videos could be neat. In the future? Who knows. If we do, I don't see it being particularly exclusive. And in any case, I like to think we're pretty good at not screwing the people who share their knowledge and donate their time on any of our sites. We do our best to be respectful.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm looking waaay down the road. And I don't mean to suggest that the SE "suits" are especially untrustworthy. I just have a long history of expecting people to behave equitably and being terrifically disappointed in the exchange:( but that's no fault of yours. I just see so much potential in this concept and I would hate to see it executed poorly. If SE tried a channel and it failed...well... how? The Wood Whisperer's last YT clip got 19k+ views in 4 days. The interest is there, it's just a matter of capturing it.